# Docker image that prints container id

Tags: docker

Im loking for a docker image that can print the container ID in a web browser, Something like the httpd that prints ("Is Working") but printint the container id.

I want to try if a load balancer that i just set up is working.

Comment: You can add/update your current image's entrypoint script to print out the container ID. Or print it out from your app (if the image is running an app).

Answer (score 1):

You can you this [image](https://github.com/mendhak/docker-http-https-echo).

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 --rm -t mendhak/http-https-echo:18
```

to start the server and then

```
curl http://localhost/hello-world
```

to get headers (including the hostname, which also happens to be this container's ID) back.

UPD:

Another way to get only the hostname is to run something like this:

```
PORT=8091
docker run --rm -it -e PORT=$PORT -p $PORT:$PORT busybox sh -c \
'while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n `cat /etc/hostname`" | nc -l -p $PORT; done'
```

Comment: Added busybox version with netcat responder.

Comment: Thanks !! i Also found this cool image https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxdemos/hello/